# Cannot assign value of type 'myRepositoryViewController' to type 'myRepositoryViewController!'

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am converting from objective C to Swift using xcode9 beta4, I am rewriting the working code of MyRepositoryViewController to MyRepositoryViewController.swift

In class MyListViewController.h in Objective C

```
@interface MyListViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyRepositoryViewController *myRepositoryController;
```

In class MyRepositoryViewController, written in Swift 3.0 or 4.0

```
class MyRepositoryViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var infoOverlayView: InfoOverlayView!
.....

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
....
 func openInfoOverlay() {
        if self.infoOverlayView == nil {
            Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InfoOverlayView", owner: self, options: nil)
            self.infoOverlayView.target? = self
        }

    }
```

I got an error

> Cannot assign value of type 'MyRepositoryViewController' to type
>   'MyRepositoryViewController!'

in the line

```
 self.infoOverlayView.target? = self
```

in MyRepositoryViewController.m it was working fine with:

```
- (void)openInfoOverlay
{
    if (self.infoOverlayView == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoOverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.infoOverlayView.target = self;
    }

}
```

I am novice in SWIFT programming and struggle with this for a few days. Any help is really appreciated. This is my first time asking on SO.

Comment: Odd error message for it, but take out the `?`.

Comment: If you are new to Swift please learn what optionals are and how to handle them. That's essential in Swift

Answer (score 0):

Ask Kevin mentioned, the ? is unnecessary , I put it in to see if it fix the problem. Thanks for all the helps.

When I go to Bridging-Header and remove MyRepositoryViewController.h, the project can be compiled.